# How soon can I get an update from a CLLocationManager?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location

I try to employ region monitoring in my app, and as far as I understand, this would trigger two methods, `didEnterRegion` and `didExitRegion` even if the app is not even in background.
So this might cause the functions get called without any awareness of the app, as if these functions are just blocks of code being called with basic app environment, but all around them is nulled. For example, if we created a CLLocationManager, it is nulled by now, and we need to create a new one.

What I need to do is get a current location from that CLLocationManager, but can I use this?

```
locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];

locationManager.delegate = self;
locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;

locationManager.distanceFilter = 0; 
[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

CLLocation *currentLocation = [locationManager location];
```

Will `currentLocation` hold a good value or will this happen only in the delegate method `didUpdateLocations`?

Comment: The delegate will have a location in about 2 to 3 seconds but you have to know that when the delegate is called the first time it doesn't hold the correct value after it has hit the delegate 2 or 3 times than the correct value comes

Comment: distanceFilter should be  assigned some values according to your requirement other wise it suck the device battery  and Don’t forget to restart the background location service if your app is killed by iOS.

Comment: @SunilSingh what do you mean by restart background location service?

Comment: iOS can kill and garbage collect your app if the OS runs low on memory.If after your app is killed and iOS then detects a location change, iOS will start your app again in the background, but you will need to manually re-enable the background location service. check here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/

Comment: I am not sure what you mean @SunilSingh, if the app is killed and a region is entered, the app will be relaunched. I couldn't find anything about re-enabling location services. PS region monitoring does not require background location updates

Answer (score 0):

The thing that persists during region monitoring is the region.  While the app is active, the delegate will be called with **a** location manager (not necessarily **the** location manager that initiated monitoring).

If the app is launched in the background, it should detect that it's being launched for region monitoring and create a location manager (and whatever else it needs to process the event).

Comment: Still, will the code get me a location in that function? Or will it happen only in the didupdatelocations delegate method?

Comment: Yes you only get location from location monitoring, region monitoring only provides in/out of a region.  But you can after being informed of a region state change get a location as you always would.  And you can used the location manager passed to the delegate -- preferable -- or create another one to get location.

Comment: Notice the currentLocatuon variable. I am asking if the value will be updated with a good value or not. Or should I wait for the didUpdateLocations....

Comment: @Ted, We need to define "good".  It will have a value in the region, but probably not as close to actual location as what the didUpdateLocation delegate will get.   One heuristic for determining how good it is is to check the timestamp on the CLLocation object and get the time interval since now.